# Align 2 Text tags horizontally react-native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I would like to align 2 text items in a row. For example

Text{key}/Text Text{value}/Text

I read in the docs about the Text element:
The  element is special relative to layout: everything inside is no longer using the flexbox layout but using text layout. This means that elements inside of a  are no longer rectangles, but wrap when they see the end of the line.

So I'm assuming I need to wrap the text in a view. I still have not solved the problem, here is a react native example of my current progress. Notice the elements wrap to a new row. How can I avoid this behavior?

https://rnplay.org/apps/F4sr7Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you messed up with this line:

```
<View style={styles.IndexTableRow,{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
```

just move backgroundColor style to the IndexTableRow and it should work

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply Smiter, I am surprised that this was the issue. In my project code I actually have color 'blue' linked to a variable and am coloring each row odd/even differently. From what I saw on a github issue this looked like the correct way to add multiple classes. Is there a better way for dynamic styling OR could you at least point me to a specific resource, I'm not finding any on the internet, official documentation, or anything.

Comment: In order to add many classes use such an approach, e.g.: <Text style={[styles.firstClass, dynamicClass]}>value</Text>. And in a render function you can write something like that: let dynamicClass = ""; if(something) dynamicClass = styles.yourDynamicClass;